# findMeetingTimes is not returning busy time slot, "minimumAttendeePercentage" is not effective

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm calling `/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes` to check users' availability.

Here is the sample request:

```
{
  "attendees": [
    {
      "type": "Required",
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "abc",
        "address": "somebody@omni.com"
      }
    }
  ],
  "minimumAttendeePercentage": 0.0,
  "timeConstraint": {
    "activityDomain":"unrestricted",
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2018-03-30T15:00:00Z",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2018-03-30T16:00:00Z",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "isOrganizerOptional": true
}
```

I scheduled a meeting with the user from `2018-03-30T15:00:00Z` to `2018-03-30T16:00:00Z`. Before the user accepting the meeting, with the same request, the API returned a time slot of `tentative` availability in `attendeeAvailability`.

If I specified the value of `minimumAttendeePercentage` to `90` or `100`, the API still returned the same response (tentative availability).

Once the user accepted it, the response became

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
    "emptySuggestionsReason": "Unknown",
    "meetingTimeSuggestions": []
}
```

No matter what `minimumAttendeePercentage` value I specified in the request, the response always the same. Looks like `minimumAttendeePercentage` is not used, the API always consider it as `50`, which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, a meeting marked as `Tentative` is *not* considered `Busy`.

A little context here helps explain why this is. At its core, `/findMeetingTimes` is attempting to return a list of potential time slots across a number of attendees. To do this it needs to determine if a given slot for a given user is "Free" or "Busy". If it determines the time user is "Free" then it returns that time slot.

When it comes across a slot that is marked `Tentative`, it is impossible for it to *conclusively* determine if that slow is "Free" vs "Busy". A Tentative Meeting is, by definition, a meeting the user has not fully committed too. It is the meeting status equivalent of "I'll attend unless something better comes along, then I won't".

Since `/findMeetingTimes` core job is to return a list of meeting time *suggestions*,  it treats `Tentative` as `Free` for the purposes of compiling the list. This allows you to handle how you wish to treat `Tentative` within the context of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The api is returning Tentative/Free time slots, which is fine. However, the api does not return busy time slot if I set the "minimumAttendeePercentage" to 0, which means I want to see all kinds of time slots. According to the document, if the confidence is 0, then the attendee's status is busy, but the api is not returning that "Busy" time slot even the attendee has meetings, and no matter what value I set in the request, "minimumAttendeePercentage" is always considered as 50.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. "minimumAttendeePercentage" property feels ineffective.
For example, specify the following conditions:

minimumAttendeePercentage = 30.0
Attendees = 3 people

If only one person is Free, the time zone is not included in the suggestions.
Why "confidence" is always 100.

# C# (use SDK)
# Graph API v1.0

Comment: We should be able to specify we do not want suggestions that tentative, or these suggestions should not have a 100 confidence. Considering that a "tentative" slot has the same confidence value as a free slot is absurd. In addition, it is not possible to ask for more suggestions.

Comment: I can't change how the API works, I can only explain what it's doing.